# GADAppOpenAd returns Error Domain=com.google.admob Code=11 "Request Error: Internal error."

Tags: ios, swift, admob

**Goal:**
i want to load ad while user will go outside the app than if user will open the app from recent or open from app(without terminated). user will show ad and it will resume working.

**Result:**
App should load add but it return me Error Domain=com.google.admob Code=11 "Request Error: Internal error."

**Error Explaination:**
Debugger window return.

```
- some : Error Domain=com.google.admob Code=11 "Request Error: Internal error." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Request Error: Internal error., gad_response_info=  ** Response Info **
    Response ID: (null)
    Network: (null)

  ** Mediation line items **
}
```

**Code Tried:**

```
    func requestAppOpenAd() {
        let request = GADRequest()
        GADAppOpenAd.load(withAdUnitID: CommonUtils.appOpenAdsTestId, //Test id : "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5662855259"
                          request: request,
                          orientation: UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait,
                          completionHandler: { (appOpenAdIn, error) in
                            if error != nil {
                                print(error?.localizedDescription)
                            }else {
                                self.appOpenAd = appOpenAdIn
                                self.appOpenAd?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
                                self.loadTime = Date()
                                print("OPEN AD IS READY...")
                            }
                          })
    }
    
    func tryToPresentAd() {
        if let gOpenAd = self.appOpenAd, let rwc = self.window?.rootViewController{
            gOpenAd.present(fromRootViewController: rwc)
            self.requestAppOpenAd()
        } else {
            self.requestAppOpenAd()
        }
    }
    
    func wasLoadTimeLessThanNHoursAgo(thresholdN: Int) -> Bool {
        let now = Date()
        let timeIntervalBetweenNowAndLoadTime = now.timeIntervalSince(self.loadTime)
        let secondsPerHour = 3600.0
        let intervalInHours = timeIntervalBetweenNowAndLoadTime / secondsPerHour
        return intervalInHours < Double(thresholdN)
    }
```

this code i tried in `sceneDelegate` and `tryToPresentAd()` this method put in `sceneDidBecomeActive` Method it will called while user will open app from recent activities.

**Research:**
i found this error in GoogleAdmob but there it don't have any description.
https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/api/reference/Enums/GADErrorCode#/c:@E@GADErrorCode@GADErrorInternalError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5662855259` this test id i think temporary blocked on live key it's working fine.